# clang failing to compile std::atomic::load with std=c++20

Tags: clang, archlinux

The following sample program is giving me problems compiling with clang and `-std=c++20`, but it compiles just fine with `-std=c++17` or with gcc (any standard).

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  double bar() const { return d; }
  std::atomic<double> d{0.1};
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << foo.bar() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
[tmp]$ clang++ test.cpp -std=c++20
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../include/c++/10.1.0/atomic:41:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../include/c++/10.1.0/bits/atomic_base.h:858:23: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'double *' with an lvalue of type 'const double *'
        __atomic_load(__ptr, __dest, int(__m));
                             ^~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../include/c++/10.1.0/bits/atomic_base.h:1056:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__atomic_impl::load<const double>' requested here
      { return __atomic_impl::load(&_M_fp, __m); }
                              ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../include/c++/10.1.0/bits/atomic_base.h:1059:52: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__atomic_float<double>::load' requested here
      operator _Fp() const noexcept { return this->load(); }
                                                   ^
test.cpp:5:31: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__atomic_float<double>::operator double' requested here
  double bar() const { return d; }
```

I can't tell if the problem is the code, clang, or OS (Arch Linux). Trying the same program on godbolt appears to compile so I guess I'm suspecting OS. Misc information:

- clang 10.0.0-3
- gcc 10.1.0-2
- Arch Linux (updated within the last week)

Is there an error in my code? Or is anyone familiar with relevant bugs that I might be hitting?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95282

Comment: Thanks, can you move that to an answer so I can mark it?